# Rsync and Photo Exif Data

Tags: unix, rsync

I have a whole bunch of family photos that I am editing over the holidays. I want to use rsync to back up to my NAS while I work on them. Will rsync update EXIF data and other metadata that I add to the photos as I continue to work on the photos ?

My plan is to back up the entire stash of photos first. Then work on them with updating EXIF, colors etc and want to make sure rsync can handle that on subsequent runs.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` command sync the files between two storages and do not care about the filetypes. When you run the program second time and have one file changed `rsync` will "see" changed file and copy it to the target place.